# One Page Checkout is almost empty

Tags: magento, checkout

I am having an almost empty one page checkout.

After clicking “Checkout” from minicart or main shopping cart page, i am getting an almost blank “Checkout” page.

The page is showing Main Top Bar including Menu bar, Minicart, currency and the bottom bar also.

But in the middle, the main Checkout page is totally blank with only ‘Checkout” text.

I checked various blogs and help on the forums itself. But i could not resolved it.

Can anybody help me out on this.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Something is likely dying in the template. Edit `index.php` to uncomment `ini_set('display_errors');` and you will see the error.

Alternatively enable logging in the admin panel, then look at `var/log/exception.log`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The Same thing happens with other THEME also.
How to see the exception.log. Do i need to login to web hosting account or the Magento admin. Where in Admin (Dashboard) can i find that file.

Comment: Also
Can you please let me know how to change the index.php file step by step exactly.